# active pseudo class not working

Tags: jquery, css

when i click on the link "home" class home should change and stay at  class home1 till another link is clicked but it doesn't...class changes but on clicking the other link 
"bye" the class of "Home" doesn't change back from home1 to home and its no longer clickable too.

**php is as**

```
    <title>TEST</title>
<link href="css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="text/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>



 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("ul.nav li").click(function(e) {
   var newclass=($(this).attr("class")+"1");
   var oldclass=($(this).attr("class"));
   alert($(this).attr("class")+"1");
   $(this).attr( "class",newclass);

 });
</script>
</head>

    <body>
        <div class=sidebar>       
                    <ul id=nav>
                        <li class="home"><a href="index.php"> Home</a></li>
                        <li class="bye"><a href="bye.php"> Bye </a></li> 
                    </ul>
         </div>
     </body> 

    </html>
```

**css**

```
body {
width:1020px;
margin:0 auto;
position:absolute;  
}

.sidebar {
    margin-left:10px;
    }
.nav {
    display:block;
    margin-top:60px;        
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    }

a{
text-decoration:none;
border:none;    
}

li.home{ 
 background: $666 no-repeat;
 width:150px;
 height:65px;
    color:#fff;
}


li.bye{ 
background: $666 no-repeat;
width:150px;
 height:65px;
    color:#fff;  
}


li.home:hover {
    background: #678fef  no-repeat;
    color:#fff;


    }
li.bye:hover {
    background: #678fef  no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
    }

li.home1 {
    background: #678fef  no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
    }
li.bye1 {
    background: #678fef  no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
    }
```

i have added jquery to the code but still no alert box or the desired result plz point me the mistake

u can see it in

plz help

Comment: do the pics change if your mouse is over li.home? css :hover means mouse over. if you want to change the image on click I believe you have to use javascript (jQuery) for that

Answer (score 1):

The :active-state is only active while you hold down the mouse-button on the link! It is not active until you click another link! This could be done with jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('a.lastClickedLink').removeClass('lastClickedLink');
    $(this).addClass('.lastClickedLink');
});
```

The link that was clicked last will have the class lastClickedLink and can then be styled through css with `a.lastClickedLink {}`.

If you want this class to be persistent when the user comes back to the page later, you will have to use a cookie. Use [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for this.

Comment: so lastClickedLink is the name of class that will replace class =home when home is click but then it will replace the class= bye too when bye is click and i have 2separate images for home and bye when they are active...is there anyway i cud append the class name like find the current class name and add 1 to its end..if so plz guide how to go about it

Comment: .addClass will not remove or replace any classes! Your links will have both classes home and lastClickedLink or bye and lastClickedLink!

Comment: i want to find the class name fir eachli and add a suffix to it 1 and then assign the new class to it e.g if it clicks class= home then in active state it gets the class name home1 ...how doi get the java/jquery to go about it..... since class=home assigns the pic home.png and home1 assigns the pic home1.png...same whenclass by assigns pic bye.png and class bye1 assigns the name bye1.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve this?

```
<!-- The CSS Section -->
<style type="text/css">
body {
  width:1020px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:absolute;
}
.sidebar {
  margin-left:10px;
}
.nav {
  display:block;
  margin-top:60px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  border:none;
}
li.home {
  background: $666 no-repeat;
  width:150px;
  height:65px;
  color:#fff;
}
li.bye {
  background: $666 no-repeat;
  width:150px;
  height:65px;
  color:#fff;
}
li.home:hover {
  background: #678fef no-repeat;
  color:#fff;
}
li.bye:hover {
  background: #678fef no-repeat;
  color:#fff;
}
li.home1 {
  background: #678fef no-repeat;
  color:#fff;
}
li.bye1 {
  background: #678fef no-repeat;
  color:#fff;
}
</style>

<!-- Importing jQuery Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Applying Custom JS Functions -->
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("ul#nav li a").click(function (e) {
        var newClass = ($(this).parent().attr('class') + 1);
        var oldClass = ($(this).parent().attr('class'));
        alert(newClass);
        $(this).parent().attr('class', newClass)
    });
});
</script>

<!-- The HTML Section -->
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="home"><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
        <li class="bye"><a href="#"> Bye </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Or simply test it on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FHsvj/

Cheers!